# Populate JS variables with ACF field value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Good evening.

I’m trying to populate variables in my custom JS script with ACF field value but I have no clue how to do it.

I’m wondering if anybody got luck with using sage with ACF javascript API?

Basically I have a script which works when I have it in scripts/common.js but I want to pull data from ACF into it. Pretty much set a variable with data from ACF.

Did anybody do that before?

Any help would be more than appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: If you expose ACF to the WP REST API (I have used this plugin, that still works despite not being updated for a while https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api) you should be able to use AJAX in your script to query the REST endpoints and store the ACF values you need.

Comment: I found a different solution - 'wp_localize_script'.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty decent solution for returning ACF data to JS by using wp_localize_script WordPress function.

Add this to your functions.php :

```html
wp_localize_script( 'your_js_file', 'acf_vars', array(
   'something' => get_field( 'custom_field' ),
  )
 );
```